# Three coloring the elements of symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Is it possible to $3$-color the elements of the symmetric group $S_n\ n\ge3$ such that all color classes have the same number of elements ($\frac{n!}{3}$); and, when elements in any  color class are acted by the set of transpositions $\{(12), (13), \ldots, (1n)\}$ we get  no element in the same class; or, to be precise,  when we act to the right by a transposition on any element to a color class, we get neighbors in both of the other color classes; and in addition, we can get a perfect matching from any two color classes.

Precisely, it is like $3$- coloring the bipartite cayley graph formed by the generating set $\{(12), (13), \ldots, (1n)\}$ on the group $S_n$, such that all color classes have same cardinality and any two color classes have a regular  nontrivial(degree $\ge$ $1$) bipartite subgraph of order $2\frac{n!}{3}$.

It is easy to see this true for $n=3$. The color classes being given by $[e, (13)(12)(13)=(23)];[(12), (13)(12)]; [(13), (12)(13)]$. However as $n$ rises, I don't see a way to get this done. Specifically, I think we have to produce $\frac{n!}{6}$ $6$-cycles in the Cayley graph mentioned. But, how can this be effectively done? Can induction work here? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Interesting question. There can't be any local obstacles (meaning small non-3-colorable subgraphs) because the Cayley graph as a whole is bipartite (using the cosets of the alternating group as the colors). I wonder if a randomized strategy could work.

Comment: I'm not sure what your idea about $6$-cycles is, but the cosets (left or right? I'll let you figure it out) of the subgroup $\langle (12),\ (13) \rangle$ are disjoint $6$-cycles.

Comment: This problem looks interesting but the exposition could be clearer. The text at the end of the 1st paragraph: *"when elements in any color class are acted by the set of transpositions.....we get no element in the same class"* is quite confusing and ambiguous. What does this mean precisely? That if say, $\pi \in S_n$ is in the 1st color class, then $\tau\pi$ [or $\pi\tau$] is in either the 2nd or 3rd color class for each such transposition $\tau$? Or that there for each $j\in \{2,3\}$ exists such a transposition $\tau_j$ so that $\tau_j\pi$ [or $\pi\tau_j$] is in the $j$-th color class?

Comment: @Mike Your second question is the one intended, that is when we act to the right by a transposition on any element to a color class, we get neighbors in both of the other classes

Comment: Thank you....Saw your edits. An additional question: That the resulting bipartite subgraph is actually **$k$-regular** for some $k\ge 1$--isn't that an additional condition from merely having **minimum degree** 1? Cayley graphs are always regular, but subgraphs of Cayley graphs in general are certainly not guaranteed to be....

Comment: @Mike yes, that is what is intended. In fact, I need not have the *induced* subgraph formed by the two color classes to be regular, but only that a perfect matching exists, or in other words, there is a $k$-regular bipartite subgraph formed by the elements of any two color classes, as you say, which ensures a perfect matching.

Comment: But even that a perfect matching exists is a priori stronger condition than having minimum degree 1 though. Even here working in a Cayley graph.

Comment: @Mike But here the graph is bipartite and, by Hall's theorem, regularity implies the existence of  a perfect matching.

Comment: Alright I saw your previous comment. But that is still a stronger condition than $\{\pi\} + \{\pi\tau$; $\tau$ a transposition of the form $\tau = (1,k)\}$ intersecting all color classes.

Comment: @Mike yes, that is. Will edit again

Comment: One of colors contains at least $n!/12$ both of even and odd permutations. Is it possible that there are no edges between such huge sets?

Comment: @FedorPetrov why should it not be possible. The graph seems quite sparse, right?

Comment: but the sets are of size comparable with the whole size of group, and degrees are much greater than constant

Comment: From the comments @vidyarthi I take that the coloring must be a *proper* coloring too...i.e., each color class forms an independent set in the Cayley graph specified. Is this correct

Comment: @Mike yes, that is true.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer yes, the left cosets provide us disjoint $6$-cycles. But, how should arrange the vertices or independent sets in each cosets so that the final set would be actually independent. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't know. I was just responding to your statement "we have to produce $\tfrac{n!}{6}$ 6-cycles in the Cayley graph mentioned. But, how can this be effectively done?"

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Actually, my conviction has grown stronger using the results I obtained from SageMath software upto $n=7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to $3$-color the elements of the Symmetric group in the way stated. The proof can be found in Theorem 1 of [MDPI Symmetry Paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/10/2173).

The proof uses a similar idea given in the comments of @DavidSpyer of taking cosets of $S_{n-1}$ with respect to $S_n$, and using induction, by knowing that the base case of $S_3$ is true.

Comment: Are you one of the authors of this paper?

Comment: @SamHopkins you're close. I leave the answer open for anonymity. By the way, do you find the proof satisfactory, or can it be improved?

Comment: Well, if you know the authors, you might inform them that if they used ideas based on comments to this MO question, probably they should acknowledge that in their paper.

Comment: @SamHopkins As the paper is already published, do you think it is necessary to add reference to the comment as an addendum in coming issues?

Comment: It's not a big deal but just something to bear in mind going forward.